# Application compiled for Windows XP does not run on Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker, static-linking

I have created an application for Windows XP using VC++ 6.0.The application runs fine on Windows XP but when I try to run this application Windows 7, it complains of missing DLL's like `msvcrt.dll`, `msvcp60.dll` etc. My users does not want to copy these DLL's manually on every system they use.

So how can I statically link these DLL's on VC++ 6.0 so that users does not have to copy the DLL's seperately.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to the C/CPP runtime libraries statically.

A static link will not have DLL dependencies on the C/C++ runtime. If your application is made out of several DLLs, you must make sure memory is not created in one binary and destroyed in another.

**Edit:**
MFC executable projects should be altered:

Project properties->General->Use of MFC
Change to "Use MFC in a static library"

Comment: Statically linking library mean adding /MT to my project options.But using /MT gives me an error.It says" use /MD switch for _afxdll". Will removing _afxdll impact my program?

Comment: MFC DLLs require /MD. If you only have an executable check out the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Select Project/Settings...

Select C/C++ Tab

Select Code Generation from the combo box

Under Library, change to multithreaded.